# Changing the Leader in MacVim?

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I'm trying to change `<Leader>` in MacVim to be something less carpal-tunnel inducing. I have added this line

```
let mapleader=","
```

to my .gvimrc, but "\" is still the only key that works. Am I missing something?

Comment: This does not seem to be MacVim specific. Can anyone confirm this? If it applies to windows/linux versions to I'd say this question should be retagged to be not macvim-specific.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The line needs to go into your normal `.vimrc` (instead of `.gvimrc`). `.gvimrc` is not read until all plugins have been loaded, by which time all the mappings have already been created with the default map leader.

`.gvimrc` is intended only for GUI-specific options, everything else should be in `.vimrc`.

Comment: I don't know if MacVim reads `.gvimrc` but I'm pretty sure it reads `.vimrc` so this should work. It might be possible to add conditional lines to your `.vimrc` to control MacVim-specific behavior.

Comment: A very useful answer and not macvim specific.

Answer (score 0):

I use macvim and it does seem to use the .vimrc I also have leader mapped to that character.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some scripts to customise your vim you may try to put the `let mapleader=","` in your `~/.vimrc.before` file. At least this did the trick for me.